# Data binding manually update in WPF MVVM

Tags: mvvm, drag-and-drop, binding

My ViewModel:

```
class ViewModel
{
public string FileName {get;set;}
}
```

and in my `View` I bind a label's content to ViewModel's `FileName`.

now When I do drag-drop a file to my View, How can I update the label's `Content` property, so that the ViewMode's `FileName` also get updated via binding?

Directly set the label's `Content` property won't work, it just simply clear the binding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3 quick choices... (Make sure the class implements INotifyPropertyChanged, and FileName is raising this event.)

1. You can simply pull the VM out of the View's DataContext and during the Drag-and-Drop event set the FileName property of the ViewModel.
2. Use an AttachedBehavior to allow the Event (Drag-and-Drop) to be used like a Command ([Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20201027180030/http://geekswithblogs.net/HouseOfBilz/archive/2009/08/27/adventures-in-mvvm-ndash-binding-commands-to-any-event.aspx))
3. Use a Messenger pattern, like MVVMLight's Messenger, to send a Message from the View to the ViewModel and handle the Message on the VM like you would a Command Action.